# Django Rest - retrive data from nested class

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my following output (below), I would like to get the value from `rating` field. As you can see there are two rates for that car model. The value from `rating` will be needed to calculate average rate for that model.

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "make": "Citroen",
    "model": "C4",
    "rates": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "rating": 4,
            "car_id": 4
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "rating": 4,
            "car_id": 4
        }
    ],
    "avg_rating": 0.0
}
```

Here is my **models.py**:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    make = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    avg_rating = models.FloatField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):      # print it when Car instance is needed
        return self.make


class CarRate(models.Model):
    car_id = models.ForeignKey(Car, related_name='rates',
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            default=0)
    rating = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

My **serializers.py**:

```
class CarRateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CarRate
        fields=('__all__')
    


class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rates = CarRateSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        rates_data = validated_data.pop("rates")
        car = Car.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for rate_data in rates_data:
            CarRate.objects.create(car=car, **rate_data)
        return car

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('id', 'make', 'model','rates','avg_rating')
```

I have no idea how to retrive those data.

Later in `views.py` while doing GET I tried to many things, i.e.

```
my_data=getattr(cars, 'rates["rating"]')
```

Like I would try to get a dict value, it didn't work.

Comment: Just curious, why are you using django framework for serialization? as in, is there additional benefit for deserialization purposes?

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to create a [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) for avg_rating in CarSerializer.

Something like this:

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rates = CarRateSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    avg_rating = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('id', 'make', 'model','rates','avg_rating')

    def get_avg_rating(self, obj):
        // obj will hold your current Car object
        // Code for finding the CarRate objects using the Car obj
        // Average calculation - avg_rating = total_rating/no_of_ratings
        return avg_rating
```

**Updated code based on the comment.**
Added a new field `avg_car_rate` which holds the average of ratings.

```
from django.db.models import Sum


class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rates = CarRateSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    avg_car_rate = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('id', 'make', 'model', 'rates', 'avg_rating', 'avg_car_rate')

    def get_avg_car_rate(self, obj):
        rates = obj.rates.all()
        avg = rates.aggregate(Sum('rating')).get('rating__sum')/rates.count()
        return avg
```

Comment: Okay, I get it, but still how to find that value. When I print it with GET method it looks like: `rates` as key, list of dicts as value. For example I type: `mylist=obj.rates.all()`, it returns list of  `CarRate object` with id. How can I get deeper? :D

Comment: The requirement is not clear. Is it like you need to show the avg_rating based on the carrate objects? See the updated code if that is what you want. Added an additional field since the purpose is not understood clearly @wolnio

Comment: @wolnio, Does it work for you?

Comment: oh, sorry, I haven't got time to test it out yet... I will give you an info when I'll do :)